# Curvature forms as exterior covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, curvature, principal-bundles

I have read on several forums like this one, that given a connection form $\omega$ on a principal bundle and its curvature form $\Omega$, I can state that $\Omega=d_\omega\omega$ alike I do in the case of torsion, namely that torsion is the covariant differential of a differential form.
To me that does not make sense, because $\Omega=d\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega]$ and there is no representation in which that $\frac{1}{2}$ can arise.

Any explanations?

Comment: There are various definitions of wedge product (which is needed to define the Lie bracket of $\mathfrak g$-valued forms); with some you get $1/2$, with others you do not. It's hard to pull formulas off web pages; you really need a coherent exposition from a text.

Comment: Ok. But the problem is the same. I did not explain properly... The covariant derivativa in my definition does not have the 1/2 in front of the commutator.

Comment: I mean, I can ask you. Can I express the curvature as a covariant derivative?

Comment: Yes, of course, the curvature can be given as the covariant derivative of the connection form, both in the principal bundle context and in the vector bundle context.

Comment: Ok great, thanks...